# XAML Binding a list and filter

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a LongListSelector Element with an ItemsSource like `ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"`
MyList is a ObservableCollection of MyObj. MyObj has two attributes an ID and a Name.

I'd like to filter MyList that only elements with the Name "test" will be displayed.

Can I do this in xaml code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ you can do this in code

```
var result = MyList.Where(w => w.Name.Equals("test"));
```

and to this in xaml you would need CollectionViewSource

Check these helpful links

http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2010/10/14/wp7-in-app-searching-filtering.html

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP8CollectionViewSource-41c362bf

http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2012/04/12/Filtering-collections-from-XAML-using-CollectionViewSource.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't filter your list in xaml, alter your `ObservableCollection` in your code behind. In case you are using `C#` this would be:

```
MyList = new ObservableCollection<MyObj>(allItems.Where(x => x.Name == "test"));
```